# ERROR: Trying to bundle file but it doesn't exist with adminjs/adminbro

Tags: javascript, express, amazon-s3, admin-bro, adminjs

I have an api with adminjs and upload feature with aws s3 that is working correctly when i run locally. But when deployed on vercel i get the following error:

```
t.Module.\_extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
Legacy server listening...
2022-12-08T12:33:06.859Z    undefined   ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"ConfigurationError: \\n    Trying to bundle file '/var/task/node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/edit' but it doesn't exist\\n    More information can be found at: https://docs.adminjs.co/AdminJS.html%5Cn    ","reason":{"errorType":"ConfigurationError","errorMessage":"\\n    Trying to bundle file '/var/task/node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/edit' but it doesn't exist\\n    More information can be found at: https://docs.adminjs.co/AdminJS.html%5Cn    ","name":"ConfigurationError","stack":\["ConfigurationError: ","    Trying to bundle file '/var/task/node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/edit' but it doesn't exist","    More information can be found at: https://docs.adminjs.co/AdminJS.html%22,%22    ","    at Function.resolveFilePath (/var/task/node_modules/adminjs/lib/backend/utils/component-loader.js:108:11)","    at ComponentLoader.\__unsafe_addWithoutChecks (/var/task/node_modules/adminjs/lib/backend/utils/component-loader.js:52:46)","    at Function.bundle (/var/task/node_modules/adminjs/lib/adminjs.js:391:41)","    at uploadFileFeature (/var/task/node_modules/@adminjs/upload/build/features/upload-file/upload-file.feature.js:75:45)","    at AdminOptions.buildResources (/var/task/src/utils/buildAdminOptions.js:235:21)","    at module.exports (/var/task/src/main/config/setup.js:18:39)","    at Object.\<anonymous\> (/var/task/src/main/config/app.js:6:1)","    at Module.\_compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)","    at Object.Module.\_extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)"\]},"promise":{},"stack":\["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: ConfigurationError: ","    Trying to bundle file '/var/task/node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/edit' but it doesn't exist","    More information can be found at: https://docs.adminjs.co/AdminJS.html%22,%22    ","    at process.\<anonymous\> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)","    at process.emit (events.js:412:35)","    at process.emit (domain.js:475:12)","    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:245:33)","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:96:32)"\]}
2022-12-08T12:33:06.863Z    undefined   ERROR   Unhandled rejection: ConfigurationError:
Trying to bundle file '/var/task/node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/edit' but it doesn't exist
More information can be found at: https://docs.adminjs.co/AdminJS.html
at Function.resolveFilePath (/var/task/node_modules/adminjs/lib/backend/utils/component-loader.js:108:11)
at ComponentLoader.\__unsafe_addWithoutChecks (/var/task/node_modules/adminjs/lib/backend/utils/component-loader.js:52:46)
at Function.bundle (/var/task/node_modules/adminjs/lib/adminjs.js:391:41)
at uploadFileFeature (/var/task/node_modules/@adminjs/upload/build/features/upload-file/upload-file.feature.js:75:45)
at AdminOptions.buildResources (/var/task/src/utils/buildAdminOptions.js:235:21)
at module.exports (/var/task/src/main/config/setup.js:18:39)
at Object.\<anonymous\> (/var/task/src/main/config/app.js:6:1)
at Module.\_compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Object.Module.\_extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
RequestId: c78d99be-b47c-4848-942d-37a81c45fe78 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

**Installed libraries and their versions**

```
"@adminjs/bundler": "^2.0.0",
"@adminjs/express": "^5.0.1",
"@adminjs/mongoose": "^3.0.0",
"@adminjs/upload": "^3.0.1",
"adminjs": "^6.6.5",
```

**Setup**

```
    require('dotenv').config();
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../../public/')));
    app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
    const adminOptions = {
        locale: adminOptions().buildLocales(),
        resources: adminOptions().buildResources(),
        branding: adminOptions().buildBranding(),
        assets: {
            styles: ['/styles.css'],
        },
    };
    AdminJS.registerAdapter({ Database, Resource });
    const admin = new AdminJS(adminOptions);
    const adminRouter = AdminJSExpress.buildAuthenticatedRouter(admin, {
        ...  
    });
    app.use(admin.options.rootPath, adminRouter);
```

**my entry file generated automatically**

```
import Component0 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/edit.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component0 = Component0
import Component1 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/list.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component1 = Component1
import Component2 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/show.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component2 = Component2
import Component3 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/edit.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component3 = Component3
import Component4 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/list.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component4 = Component4
import Component5 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/show.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component5 = Component5
import Component6 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/edit.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component6 = Component6
import Component7 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/list.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component7 = Component7
import Component8 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/show.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component8 = Component8
import Component9 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/edit.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component9 = Component9
import Component10 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/list.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component10 = Component10
import Component11 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/show.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component11 = Component11
import Component12 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/edit.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component12 = Component12
import Component13 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/list.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component13 = Component13
import Component14 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/show.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component14 = Component14
import Component15 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/edit.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component15 = Component15
import Component16 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/list.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component16 = Component16
import Component17 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/show.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component17 = Component17
import Component18 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/edit.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component18 = Component18
import Component19 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/list.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component19 = Component19
import Component20 from '../node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/show.tsx'
AdminJS.UserComponents.Component20 = Component20
```

I already tried to use @adminjs/bundler with `ADMIN_JS_SKIP_BUNDLE="true"`, but i'm not sure if i'm doing it correctly.

And my project an only .js app.